# How to have multiple filters for fixture meta in .testcaferc cofiguration file?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am having below filter defined for fixture meta in the `.testcaferc.json` file.

```
{
 "filter": {
        "fixtureMeta": {
            "FixtureType": "Smoke",
            "ProjectName": "CI"           
        }
    }
}
```

now i am using the command

```
npx testcafe chrome e2e/tests --filter.fixtureMeta
```

which is actually running the tests with meta `FixtureType` equlas to value `Smoke` and `ProjectName` equals to value `CI`

**My Question is**

how to add one more filter for fixture meta to the configuration file and make it run using the command?

for example 
if i have config like following

```
{
 "filter": {
        "fixtureMeta": {
            "FixtureType": "Smoke",
            "ProjectName": "CI"           
        }
    },
 "filter": {
        "fixtureMeta": {
            "FixtureType": "Smoke",
            "ProjectName": "CTS"           
        }
    }
}
```

how can i have multiple filters as defined above and two different commands to run those different projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`--fixture-meta`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#--fixture-meta-keyvaluekey2value2) flag from TestCafe CLI and create two commands:

```
npx testcafe chrome e2e/tests --fixture-meta FixtureType=Smoke,ProjectName=CI

npx testcafe chrome e2e/tests --fixture-meta FixtureType=Smoke,ProjectName=CTS
```